How to make Verification activity not skipping queued automation in Automation studio File drop
I have a file drop automation in marketing cloud with a verification activity in the middle.
3 files will be dropped in the sftp folder location which will trigger and queue 3 instances of this automation.
Are there anyway for the Verification activity to stop the current instance of the automation only and let the queued automation continue to run instead of being skipped like in the photo?
Thank you very much for your time.


Verification Activity already stops the current instance of the automation, so nothing you need to do about that. You would rather need to focus on skipped runs that happen when an automation has not finished the previous run and got triggered in the meanwhile again. Think about reducing the run duration or splitting the automation.

Please help me understand. If the verification is triggered, you want the automation to stop but also you want it to run again for the next schedule?

thanks Niko and @AugustRimmen, in this case the automation triggered and queued for total of 3 times because 3 files are dropped in this location. The first instance of the automation passed the verification step and completed. The second instance of the automation in the queue did not pass the verification and stepped. I would like the third instance to be executed even if the second verification stoped the second instance. In this case, it will be always be skipped if the verification step before it failed and nothing I can do currently.

Okay, so if the verification activity is not passed you want it to skip the last import file activity, but it should not stop the automation. In this case it should still consider the third file. Is that correctly understood?

Correct @AugustRimmen, thanks for your confirmation

Currently, there is no 'skip activity' option in automation studio. However, there are always some creative workarounds. One idea is to handle the import file activity with an API, thus only calling it when the criteria is met. Can you handle the logic currently in the verification activity with SSJS?
See a similar use case here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252457/verification-to-skip-an-activity-in-automation-studio
